# The current configured Flutter SDK is not known to be fully supported. Please update your SDK and restart IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart

After starting my project today I found my IntelliJ showing a banner on top. I am adding a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the versions of the tools you are using (Flutter SDK, Flutter plugin, IDEA), I've dug into the IDEA's [Flutter plugin](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij) repo to check when is that warning shown.

So you [get that warning](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/blob/8711dbba1ffbacb408a387410377704f3bb6720e/src/io/flutter/inspections/SdkConfigurationNotificationProvider.java#L76) when you either (1) don't have Flutter SDK installed on your OS and configured in your IDE, or (2) your installed version is less than [minimum recommended](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/blob/master/src/io/flutter/sdk/FlutterSdkVersion.java#L21) version 0.0.12.

I doubt it's the latter (you would have had to go back 2.5 years to find that relic). For the former, since the plugin needs the Flutter SDK, make sure you follow [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) if you haven't already to get the latest Flutter SDK, and then configure that path within your IDE (*File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter -> Flutter SDK path*).

Answer (score 6):

Restarting my computer and IDE worked for me. If that doesn't work run `flutter upgrade` in your Terminal

Comment: This fixes all computer problems.

Answer (score 1):

##### In my case it was because the owner of the flutter directory was an admin user and android studio was ran as non-admin.

I went and changed the owner of the flutter folder to my current user and it got fixed

you can change the owner of a file or folder like so:
**properties > security > advanced > (owner) ️ change**
then type in the username of your current user and hit **"Check Names"**, hit apply and its done.

Comment: Thanks your answer is correct. I changed the permission and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users:
In my case, I was setting up Flutter and Android Studio on a fresh install of MacOS. I had flutter installed, but not yet XCode. (Takes a while to download.) After XCode was installed, the message was no longer visible on the next restart of Android Studio.